# Hardware requirements for 10Gbps line rate packet processing

Tags: hardware, network

How do I calculate the horse power required for worst case packet processing scenarios?

First, a little more background, I'm building a device for packet analysis. My test box currently runs on Linux with an Intel chip set and using DPDK for packet capture. I want to support at least 10Gbps links.

Not counting jumbo frames, the line rate for Ethernet packets on a 10Gbps link is between 812,740 and 14,880,960 packets a second. So when I say worst case, that implies having to process the max payload size. In order to sustain line rate processing of 812,740 pp/s what kind of hardware is necessary? I know the actual analytics will play a big role but I haven't yet optimized or profiled the algorithms however, getting at least a minimum hardware baseline will still be helpful.

So, what I'm trying to understand is the hardware piece and I have a lot of questions; x86 vs ARM vs MIPS, CPU speed and cores, memory configuration and bus speed, temporary disk storage settings, etc.

What kind of minimum hardware configurations can support 812,740 pp/s on a 10Gbps link?

Comment: AFAIK this is more of an ASIC or FPGA job than a microprocessor job. Typically an ASIC puts the packets into a memory buffer, and a microprocessor comes along and does work on them later at substantially lower rate (i.e., it couldn't sustain processing the data at full rate indefinitely). Details depend of course on exactly *what* processing you need to do on the packet data.

Comment: You'll probably have more trouble handling the min packet size than the max, because the amount of packets is much higher.

Comment: Use GHZ speed FPGA's to capture and convert to parallel data, then as mention by Photon stuff it into a deep memory buffer. It can be an ultra fast FIFO that has empty, half full and full flags that a fast CPU can read and re-package the data into a usable format. That is a suggestion because it is easy to write that, but a nightmare to implement.

Comment: What are the end results of your test box? Just link tests? with stats on Thruput, Latency and Alerts?   PTP?, Multihosts or clients? or LAN?

Comment: Processing this much of bandwidth on a CPU is very troublesome. Using ASIC/FPGA is the best option. I am currently working on 10G - 100G deep packet analysis project. Using a FPGA is the best option we came up with after some analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This work (to both send and capture) is already well detailed and readily available.

Intel have a full [demo](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/software/download/refdesigns/ip/interface/dnl-10gbe-hardware-demo.html) available with all the code and support.

Of course you could simply buy an [Intel 10Gbps interface](https://ark.intel.com/products/88208/Intel-Ethernet-Converged-Network-Adapter-X550-T1) for about $300 and use a conventional PC (i7 with PCIe 3.0) with lots of DRam or a disk array to do your captures.
If you intend to do inline packet processing then you are probably best to use a very large memory configuration (128GB) and set aside 100GB as a Ram disk. this way you can process and move data using simple mem-cpy or mem-map to move data.

Comment: Good suggestion with the RAM disk.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you intend to do with the packets.  Simply bringing them in from the wire is doable with DPDK and a supported NIC on any relatively recent core i7 CPU.  Whatever you intend to do with the packets after you've collected them is probably going to be your bottleneck.

Also, it's the minimum length packets that are going to stress the system more as generally you're going to look at the headers on each packet only, and this depends more on the packet arrival rate than on anything else (packet size, line rate, etc.).  If you intend to look at more than just the headers, then you may need to consider load-balancing across several hosts.  This is already assuming you're load balancing across several CPU cores and perhaps even multiple CPU sockets.

If you're trying to build custom hardware for some reason, then you should probably look in to something FPGA based.  However, it's not clear from your description if this would be any better or worse than just using a reasonably powerful off-the-shelf server running DPDK.

Comment: My prototype box using an old Xeon with DPDK can handle 1Gig links no problem.  So I know standard hardware should be more than capable to capture off the wire.  Interesting that minimum length packets would stress more though.  I would of thought the memory operations on fewer larger packets would be worse than just examining more smaller packet headers.

Comment: The NIC handles receiving packets with large block DMA transfers directly into main memory.  It's really the per-packet processing overheads you have to worry about - each packet gets its own buffer, etc.  Also, transferring smaller packets over PCIe will have more overhead because PCIe usually transfers blocks of 128 or 256 bytes at a time in what's called a "transaction layer packet" that itself has headers...if your packets are 64 bytes long, then that's a lot more PCIe TLP headers eating up your PCIe bandwidth.  But the bottleneck is likely going to be your processing, not the NIC/DPDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use GHZ speed FPGA's to capture and convert to parallel data, then as mention by Photon stuff it into a deep memory buffer. It can be an ultra fast FIFO that has empty, half full and full flags that a fast CPU can read and re-package the data into a usable format.

I suggest that the serial data be converted to 64 bit wide data that is not yet aligned, but first you want to capture it in a parallel format to avoid a bottle-neck or having to use push-back commands. Use fast 64 bit hardware FIFO's for the non-aligned buffer and a 64 bit fast CPU because you want the final output to be aligned in its original format.

You might want to check with National Instruments LabVIEW and their ready-to-use hardware and software to speed things up. This is going to be expensive no matter how you do it.

Comment: All good suggestions but I'm not familiar enough with FPGAs to program or integrate into a solution.